# Always a memory leak even though I free'd all allocates

Tags: c, valgrind, free

I can't seem to find the problem to why there is always a leak with the `prio_q_create` function. I do free it with `prio_q_destroy` but valgrind still shows a leak error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct prio_q prio_q;
typedef struct elem elem;
struct prio_q {
    int size;           
    struct elem *first; 
};

struct elem {
    void *data;
    int prio;
    struct elem *next;
};

struct prio_q *prio_q_create() {
    prio_q *list = calloc(1, sizeof(prio_q));
    list->first = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}

void prio_q_push(struct prio_q *q, void *data, int prio) {
    elem *e = calloc(1, sizeof(elem));
    e->prio = prio;
    e->data = data;
    e->next = NULL;
    if (q->first == NULL) {
        q->first = e;
        q->size = q->size + 1;
    } else {
        if (q->first->prio < prio) {
            e->next = q->first;
            q->first = e;
            q->size = q->size + 1;
        } else {
            elem *temp = q->first;
            while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->prio >= prio) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            e->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = e;
            q->size = q->size + 1;
        }
    }
}

void *prio_q_pop(struct prio_q *q) {
    if (q->first != NULL) {
        elem *temp = q->first;
        q->first = q->first->next;
        void *data = temp->data;
        temp->next = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return data;
    } else
        exit(0);
}

void *prio_q_front(struct prio_q *q) {
    return q->first->data;
}

void prio_q_destroy(struct prio_q *q) {
    elem *temp = q->first;                 
    elem *next_temp;                           
    while (temp != NULL) {        
        next_temp = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = next_temp;        
    } 
    free(q);
}

int main() {
    struct prio_q *queue;
    char *s;
    int i;

    queue = prio_q_create();

    prio_q_push(queue, "amet...", 2);
    prio_q_push(queue, "ipsum", 7);
    prio_q_push(queue, "dolor", 4);
    prio_q_push(queue, "Lorem", 22);
    prio_q_push(queue, "sit", 3);

    prio_q_push(queue, "Hello World", 1);
    prio_q_push(queue, "Bye World", 0);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        s = prio_q_pop(queue);
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }

    s = prio_q_front(queue);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    prio_q_destroy(queue);
    return 0;
}
```

Should be the whole code. The main mostly pushes some strings with prio number onto the list and prints them out via a loop.
[image: The valgrind error]

Comment: you have to show the code that calls those functions.

Comment: if you compile with the following flags ```-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak``` using gcc, you should get improved memory debugging information.

Comment: At least the 1st snippet has a bug, it fails to initialize the *next* member.  The 2nd snippet has a very probable bug by starting at *first* instead of q, probably that one.  Debug this with a *small* number of nodes and inverse priority so first doesn't point to the first node.

Comment: You need to include all the relevant code to reproduce the problem What is `struct prio_q` ? Where is `main()`? ok. Where are the `#include`s ? Or do you don't use any?

Comment: Can you minimize the test code? Push as few elements as possible. Is popping necessary? If not, remove it; otherwise, please include `prio_q_pop()` (and that's a strong clue!). As @KamilCuk says, we need to see `struct prio_q`. Please include all the code necessary so that we can literally just paste your code into a file and compile it; it should be a [mcve].

Comment: the prio_q is the head of the list. It points to other elements with a priority number, void* data and a next pointer.

Comment: It isn't a cause of the memory leak, but the code `struct prio_q * prio_q_create() {
    prio_q *list = calloc(1,sizeof(prio_q)); …` uses both `struct prio_q` and `prio_q`.  You should be self-consistent — use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: print addresses after every allocation and you will easily discover what was not freed. Simple debugging

Comment: Add a `printf("Doing early termination\n"),` statement immediately before the `exit(0);` in `prio_q_pop()`, and run the test again.  If that prints, then you know why you got a leak — but you don't (yet) know why you have fewer elements than you expected in the queue.

Comment: Also, when you're using Valgrind, it is usually a good idea to show (an appropriate subset of) the output from Valgrind.  If there are any other problems reported, that is significant — and those should probably be fixed first.

Comment: Another 'not the cause of the leak' issue. In `prio_q_push()`, you have the code structure: `if(q->first == NULL) { … } else { if(q->first->prio < prio) { … } else { … } }` — Your indentation is wonky, but that's caused because you use `else { if (…) {` rather than just `else if (…) {`. The brace between the `else` and the `if` means you need the extra brace below — and you've indented your code so that consecutive lines have a `}` at the same level of indentation. In my view, two consecutive close braces at the same level of indentation always indicates some formatting problem.

Comment: @HoanNhat:  Did you run the MCVE code from the question to get this Valgrind output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no leak in the posted code. Either you are testing code that is not posted or your version of Valgrind might detect a false positive caused by the C library allocating a buffer for `stdout`. Try without the `printf` statements.

Here is my Valgrind trace:

```
chqrlie$ make memleak
gcc -O2 -funsigned-char -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -W -Wmissing-field-initializers -lm -o memleak memleak.c
chqrlie$ valgrind ./memleak
==45671== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==45671== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==45671== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==45671== Command: ./memleak
==45671==
amet...
ipsum
dolor
Lorem
sit
Hello World
==45671==
==45671== HEAP SUMMARY:
==45671==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==45671==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 184 bytes allocated
==45671==
==45671== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==45671==
==45671== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==45671== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
chqrlie$
```

Comment: Or, the OP is not running the code that is now in the question, and has a different problem not illustrated by the code, so it isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]) after all, because it isn't verifiable — it doesn't reproduce the problem.  But I can't see a leak in the code shown (but Valgrind doesn't compile on macOS Mojave, which is irksome).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, I suspect the MCVE that is posted may behave differently from the OP's code split into multiple files with potentially more unposted code. OS/X support for Valgrind is something I should fix too, I had to use linux for testing.

Comment: @HoanNhat: I get the same Valgrind output with the updated parameters... consistent with our reading of the code where we cannot locate any leaks.

Comment: It was indeed a problem on my end. I don't have valgrind( since it doesn't work on Mac) so I sent it to my friend who tested it for me. Turns out he forgot delete some lines in his main from when he was testing. Thank you guys for all the help.